# Model passed to Razor partial is null, despite it being checked as non-null by caller

Tags: asp.net-core, razor

This is puzzling me. Look at the lower code around line 215, then the higher code around line 6.

The dashboard page Razor code only calls `<partial ...` if the model to be sent in is not null, but then the null check in the partial view throws because the model is null.

Any ideas?

[image: Screenshot of error showing null checks where one passes and the other fails]

---

**Update**

The plot thickens. The debugger shows the `Model.ManageAssignmentsButton` property is null but it runs the code in the `if` block anyway!

[image: Debugger shows property is null]

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

So to test the wider block, I'd moved this code outside of another `else` block by shifting the whole lot down a single line so it sat outside some `{}` braces.

I'm using VSCode on macOS and I'm more used to using full VS on Windows, so I didn't realise the formatter/colorizer is broken so it looked perfect when in fact it was not.

Adding `@` to the front of the `if` statements fixed it.